# Compactness and closedness

Tags: general-topology, analysis, compactness

If every closed and proper subset of a topological space $X$ is compact, then is the whole space necessarily compact?

The "converse" of this question is well-known, of course, but I'm having difficulty establishing a proof of this. Also, no counterexamples spring to mind either.

Comment: Wouldn't the whole space be compact by the simple fact that, trivially the whole space is a subset of itself (assuming that the whole space is closed)?

Comment: @rocinante OP specified *proper* subspaces.

Comment: Note that it would suffice to find two proper closed subsets (not necessarily disjoint) whose union is the whole space.

Comment: If $\cal O$ is a cover of the space and $O\in\cal O$, then $\cal O$ is a cover of the closed set $O^C$.

Comment: @12455421 I don't understand your question. Those are not compact...evidently the property you're suggesting does not hold for $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: could you please elaborate? are you saying it's true, and that no counterexample can be found?

Comment: @12455421 that would work if $\mathbb{R}$ were a space satisfying the premise of your question.  And if you do mean the two-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$, then yes that does work.

Comment: Yes. Choose $O$ so that $O^C$ is proper (if no such $O$ exists, any $O$ covers $X$). Then finitely many elements of $\cal O$ cover $O^C$. Toss in $O$ and you have a cover of $X$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Your answer is perfectly straight-forward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An equivalent definition of compactness is the following:

*A space $X$ is compact if and only if every family of closed subsets of $X$ with the finite intersection property has non-empty intersection.*

We say that a family $\mathcal F$ of sets has the finite intersection property if 
$F_1\cap\cdots\cap F_n\ne\varnothing$,
for every $n$ and $F_1,\ldots,F_n\in\mathcal F$. (See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space).)

Assume now that $\mathcal C$ is a family of closed subsets of $X$ with the finite intersection property, and $F\in\mathcal C$, with $F\ne X$. It is already given that $F$ is compact. Then clearly the family
$$
\tilde{\mathcal C}\,=\,\big\{F\cap C: C\in\mathcal C\big\},
$$
is another family of closed subsets of $X$ with the finite intersection property, and as they are also closed subsets of $F$, which is assumed compact, 
the family $\tilde{\mathcal C}$ has non-empty intersection, and so does 
family ${\mathcal C}$.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

Let $T$ be the topological space. Let $U_{i}\neq\emptyset, i\in I$ be an open cover.

Let $i_{0}\in I$ and consider $T^{'}:=T\setminus U_{i_{0}}$. $T^{'}$ is a proper subspace and thus there is a finite subset $I_{F}\subset I$ such that $\left\{U_{i}\right\}_{i\in I_{F}}$ is an open cover for $T^{'}$ but this means that $\left\{U_{i}\right\}_{i\in I_{F}\cup\left\{i_{0}\right\}}$ is a finite open cover for $T$.

Editet it twice, in this version I don't need Zorn's lemma. Check if I forgot something plx :-)

Comment: "w.l.o.g. such that you cannot remove any set without losing the covering property" - Can you explain why this is possible?

Comment: hah, already done before you asked! I knew someone would state that :-)

Comment: if you still don't believe me say so.

Comment: It is true, but not trivial. You need Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: interesting, thanks! Puzzling with that one is always fun :-)

Comment: short fun... the semi order to choose is inclusion, the maximal elements are the intersections and the maximality gives the result.

Comment: How is your T' here closed?

Comment: yes, you are right, $T^{'}$ hat to be $T\setminus U_{i_{0}}$.

Comment: and i dont need zorn if i do it this way

Comment: @Max: Now your version makes complete sense, and is exactly the same as what David Mitra suggested above in the comments to my question.

Comment: oh... lol... didn't notice :-)